# Statet in eclipse does not find the rj package

Tags: eclipse, r, statet

I cannot get Eclipse, Statet, and R to work together. I receive an error when I launch R:

> Launching the R Console was cancelled, because it seems starting the R engine failed. 
>   Please make sure that R package 'rj' (2.0 or compatible) is installed and that the R library paths are set correctly for the R environment configuration 'R test'.

I have installed Eclipse Luna (64 bit), Statet, Java 1.8.0_25 (64bit) and R 3.1.2 (64bit). I am running on windows 7 (64bit). As required I installed the packages "rj" and "rj.gd" using:

```
install.packages(c("rj", "rj.gd"), repos="http://download.walware.de/rj-2.0")
```

It installed fine:

```
packageDescription("rj") 

Encoding: UTF-8  
Package: rj  
Version: 2.0.2-1  
Title: RJ - R Package for high-level Java-R library RJ  
Author: Stephan Wahlbrink, Tobias Verbeke, low-level R binding based on the JRI library by Simon Urbanek  
Maintainer: Stephan Wahlbrink <stephan.wahlbrink@walware.de>  
Depends: R (>= 2.11.0)  
Suggests: rj.gd  
SystemRequirements: java  
Description: Server implementation and R functions for the high-level Java-R library   RJ. The package also includes callback functions for StatET.  It is shipped with an adapted version of the JRI library.  The package can be used only when R was loaded via RJ.  
License: LGPL (>= 2.1)  
URL: http://www.walware.de/goto/opensource  
Packaged: 2014-07-11 15:43:15 UTC; build  
Built: R 3.1.1; x86_64-w64-mingw32; 2014-07-11 15:47:59 UTC; windows 

-- File: c:/~/R/win-library/3.1/rj/Meta/package.rds
```

I made sure that the library path is correct. I am a bit at a loss, how to proceed.

thanks for the help.

Christoph

Answer (score 4):

Whilst digging around in the R-environment configuration (Run -> Run configurations... -> R config -> Configure), I tried something which worked: 
Instead of specifying the user library link under "R_LIBS_USER", add an entry under "R_LIBS_SITE".

It works fine after that.

(I would have included visual pointers, but no rep)

Comment: What is the value you added for R_LIBS_USER?

Comment: @WarrenP (and likely enough for myself in a year when I get a new machine and struggle to set StatET up again): use the directory where R installs its packages, which for me currently is `.../Documents/R/win-library/3.5`.

Comment: So you can't post a screenshot because you only have 46 rep? Send me the imgur link and I'll post it.

Answer (score 1):

I set R_LIBS_USER to the /library/ folder in the R environment and it worked fine.

[image]